# $\omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt3 i}{2}$ , $ \omega^5 = ? $

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> > $\omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt3 i}{2} $, $ \omega^5 = ? $

$\omega^3 = 1$ by definition?
So, $\omega^5 = \omega^2$

But why do i get wrong answer?

Comment: $\omega^5=1/\omega=\bar \omega$

Comment: Normally, $\omega$ denotes a cube root of $1$ (the one that lies in the second quadrant): $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt 3i}{2}$. Here the question rather sneakily uses $\omega$ to denote a cube root of $-1$, which perhaps explains your confusion. But note that $\omega^3$ doesn't equal anything _by definition_; it is rather a question of convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by definition, just check that
$$\omega=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i=(\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

If you make $\omega^3$, then you have $e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot 3}=e^{i\pi}=-1$.

So $\omega^5=\omega^3\omega^2=-\omega^2$ is your mistake

Comment: Btw. It just you typed w instead of $\omega$

Comment: im going to change it now ;)

Answer (score 5):

Because $\omega=\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)$ and therefore it is *not* true that $\omega^3=1$. Actually, $\omega^3=-1$. And$$\omega^5=-\omega^2=-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)=\frac{1-i\sqrt3}2.$$

Comment: https://www.math-only-math.com/the-cube-roots-of-unity.html

Comment: That text is about $-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help.. But i more understand what Luise said..

Comment: He means that you write wrong the number $w$ in your question. maybe that leads the wrong solution you got

Answer (score 0):

$$ \omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt3 i}{2} =e^{i\pi/3 }$$

$$ \omega^5 = e^{5i\pi/3 } = \cos (5\pi /3)+i\sin(5\pi /3) = 1/2 -i\sqrt 3 /2$$

Comment: True answer. Thank you